# Repeat Function over multiple columns

Tags: python

I'd like to apply the below over all columns in a df. Is there a way to do that without specifying each and every column?

```
def conditions(x):
    if x['Column1'] ==0:
        return "N/A"
    elif x['Column1'] == x['Name_CleanCorrect']:
        return 1
    else:
        return 0
    
df_third['Column1_Correct'] =  df_third.apply(conditions, axis=1)
```

Comment: Wouldn't a simple for-loop work? `for col in df.columns: ...`

Comment: Might work, sorry i'm pretty new to python. How would i get it to add a column for each column it applied against?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterate over the columns in a for-loop, I've made minimal changes to your code:

```
def conditions(x, colname):
    if x[colname] ==0:
        return "N/A"
    elif x[colname] == x['Name_CleanCorrect']:
        return 1
    else:
        return 0

for col in df_third.columns:    
    df_third[col + '_Correct'] = df_third.apply(conditions, axis=1, args=(col,))
```

Also note that comparison operations like these are built into pandas: you can compare entire columns with eachother at once, so you don't have to do it row-wise through apply. For example:

```
df_third.loc[df_third[col] == 0, col + '_Correct'] = "N/A"
```

uses `df_third[col] == 0` as indexing object. See the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing).

Comment: Thanks Swier! this works great. i'll have to dive into the Python way a little more to get it right, but looks like that would be better for larger database. thanks again.

Comment: when i run the pandas method, i'm only getting the last column compared and only an "N/A" when it is 0 but not a 1 when same or or 0 when not same? Noticed my method is slow and would like to use the recommended form if possible.